# Change ImageView from another activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with some buttons lets say every list has button_1 and button_2 when i click button_1 i will go to next intent but will not `finish()` the previews activity and then on my present activity there is a button_3 and if i click button_3 the button_2 from previous activity will change too when i go back. now my question is is there a way we can pass a view from another activity or is it possible to call `setNotifyOnChange()` on another activity?

Answer (score 1):

just call setNotifyOnChange() in onResume() method of the previous activity